# Access a function from another class

Tags: java, android

i have 4 classes in my app cardclick.java , DatabaseHelper.java , homeframgment.java and recyclerAdapterhomesubjectList.java

I have a function populateArrayList(); in homefragment in which i want to call every time onclick(){present in recyclerAdapterHomesubjectList} is called. can someone help me in achieving that

homefragment::

```
package com.example.app100.RecylerAdapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import com.example.app100.R;
import com.example.app100.Subject;
import com.example.app100.card_click;
import com.example.app100.ui.home.HomeFragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerAdapterHomeSubjectList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Subject> subject;
    private Context context;


    public RecyclerAdapterHomeSubjectList(ArrayList<Subject> a, Context context){
        this.subject = a;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from((parent.getContext()));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_home_subject, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view) {
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ImageView imageView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_card_subject_imageview);
        switch (position % 3) {
            case 2:
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back1);
                break;
            case 1:
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2);
                break;
            case 0:
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back3);
                break;

        }
        Subject data = subject.get(position);
        String name = data.subject_name;
        TextView subject_name = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_card_subject_name);
        subject_name.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subject.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , card_click.class);
            intent.putExtra("name" , subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).subject_name);
            intent.putExtra("class_good" , subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).class_attended);
            intent.putExtra("class_missed" , subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).class_missed);
            intent.putExtra("credits",subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).credits);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

DatabaseHelper::

```
package com.example.app100;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String table_name = "SUBJECT_LIST";
    private static final String COL0 = "ID";
    private static final String COL1 = "NAME";
    private static final String COL2 = "CREDITS";
    private static final String COL3 = "CLASS_ATTENDED";
    private static final String COL4 = "CLASS_MISSED";


    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, table_name, null, 6);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + table_name + "("+
                COL0+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL1 + " TEXT, " +
                COL2 + " INTEGER, "+
                COL3 + " INTEGER, "+
                COL4 + " INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    boolean addData(String name, int credit , int good , int bad){
        SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1 , name);
        contentValues.put(COL2 , credit);
        contentValues.put(COL3 , good);
        contentValues.put(COL4 , bad);

        long result = db.insert(table_name , null , contentValues);
        return result != -1;
    }

    public Cursor getdata(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM SUBJECT_LIST;";
        return db.rawQuery(query , null);
    }



    void append_data(String str, String name , int goodbad) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(str, goodbad);
        int count = db.update(table_name, contentValues, "NAME = ?", new String[]{name});
        Log.d(TAG, "blue button is pressed");
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

cardclick:

```
package com.example.app100;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class card_click extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView attendace_info;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView credits;
    TextView progress_percent;
    int bad;
    int good;
    Button add;
    Button minus;
    ImageButton performance;
    String name;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_click);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.hide();

        performance = findViewById(R.id.card_click_performance_add);
        progress_percent = findViewById(R.id.card_click_progress_bar_percent);
        attendace_info = findViewById(R.id.card_click_attendance_text);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.card_click_progress_bar);
        credits = findViewById(R.id.card_click_credits_show);
        add = findViewById(R.id.card_click_add_button);
        minus = findViewById(R.id.card_click_minus_button);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        good = intent.getIntExtra("class_good", 0);
        bad = intent.getIntExtra("class_missed", 0);
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        credits.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("credits", 0)));
        display();


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                good++;
                databaseHelper.append_data("CLASS_ATTENDED", name , good);
                display();

                Cursor data = databaseHelper.getdata();
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    int a = data.getInt(3);
                    if( a > 0)
                        System.out.println("database has been updated");
                }

            }
        });
        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bad++;
                databaseHelper.append_data("CLASS_MISSED", name, bad);
                display();

                Cursor data = databaseHelper.getdata();
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    int b = data.getInt(4);
                    if( b > 1)
                        System.out.println("database has been updated");
                }
            }
        });

        performance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(card_click.this, add_performace.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });



    }


    void display(){
        int per = 100;
        if(good+bad != 0)
            per = (int)(good*100.0)/(good+bad);
        String str = "You have atttended "+ (good) +
                " out of " + (good + bad) +
                " classes";
        attendace_info.setText(str);
        progressBar.setProgress(per);
        progress_percent.setText(String.valueOf(per));
    }


}
```

RecyclerAdapterHomeSubjectList:

```
package com.example.app100.RecylerAdapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import com.example.app100.R;
import com.example.app100.Subject;
import com.example.app100.card_click;
import com.example.app100.ui.home.HomeFragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerAdapterHomeSubjectList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Subject> subject;
    private Context context;


    public RecyclerAdapterHomeSubjectList(ArrayList<Subject> a, Context context){
        this.subject = a;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from((parent.getContext()));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_home_subject, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view) {
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ImageView imageView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_card_subject_imageview);
        switch (position % 3) {
            case 2:
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back1);
                break;
            case 1:
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back2);
                break;
            case 0:
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back3);
                break;

        }
        Subject data = subject.get(position);
        String name = data.subject_name;
        TextView subject_name = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_card_subject_name);
        subject_name.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subject.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , card_click.class);
            intent.putExtra("name" , subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).subject_name);
            intent.putExtra("class_good" , subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).class_attended);
            intent.putExtra("class_missed" , subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).class_missed);
            intent.putExtra("credits",subject.get(getAdapterPosition()).credits);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can call the activity method from your adapter like this(context(YourActivity)).yourMethod (only Public methods) and if you want to call the database method from adapter just create a new instance inside the adapter or you can also pass the adapter instance in recycler constructor. In your case pass the fragment instance in your recycler adapter then you can use this instance to call fragment method (public methods)  Ask if you want another help

Answer (score 0):

just import the class name and you can use the function from it. (function and the class should be public to use)

Comment: it is not working as intended I want to update the ArrayList Subject of Homefragment every time recyclerView card is pressed